# Trouble saving an Excel document as tab delimited file with japanese Shift-JIS

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2016, language, shift-jis

Trying to save an excel document containing Japanese characters as a tab delimited file with Japanese Shift-JIS

I have done the following steps.

### Change the character encoding setting in the following steps before entering the product information in the template.

1. Click on "File", "Save As", and select save location.
2. Click on " Tools" in the lower right of the next screen, and click on "Web Options".
3. In the "Encoding" tab, select "Japanese (Shift-JIS)" from the pull-down menu of "Save this document as:".

   ### 4. Click on "OK".

3) After complete changing the character encoding to "Japanese (Shift-JIS)", enter the product information in the template.
4) Save the file as "Text (Tab delimited)" format.

However, when opening the saved text file I can see that it has not saved correctly due to hundreds of "???????????????????????"

You can recreate the problem by inserting some Japanse text こんにちは、私の名前はジェニーです and try to save it according to the instructions above. The result should not be ???????????????????????

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried copy the Excel file into the .txt file, then change the data format manually ( For example, the data for each cell is separated by a tab \t, and each line is separated by a newline character \n. Special characters are still normal) and Change the txt file encoding to utf-8.

Or you can refer to [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1400050/exporting-from-excel-to-csv-replaces-japanese-characters-with-even-though-wi) similar thread to see if it helps.